# Detect change in multiple class

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```html
<div class="a"> 18 </div>
<div class="b"> 45 </div>
<div class="a"> 50 </div>
```

I want to detect any changes for the "a" class dynamically using javascript
I've read some things about MutationObsever but didnt managed to do what I wanted...

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Yes, what changes the classes? If it's your code, then you can easily track when you change them. No need to monitor them to know when they've been changed.

Comment: It's not my code, i'm monitoring a website

Comment: Ah... And that's all the info we have? :) Like, how do you monitor this website?

Comment: I'm trying to do a firefox extension on a website to display a sound whenever there is a change
I'm using Javascript and as I said trying a MutationObserver, thats all i can say ^^'

Comment: oooh, that makes more sense. But unfortunately I don't have the answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, you need a MutationObserver when you wanna look for all the changes to the Dom.

I created a example for you, when you click on all the elements which are class "a", they change and the observer realize it and gives you an throwback.

```js
// Get all the targets with the class "a"
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.a');

//Adds an Example onclick event to change something with the dom
for(let i = 0;i<targets.length;i++){
    targets[i].onclick = ()=>{
        targets[i].classList.toggle("marked");
    }
}

// Creates an observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Creates the callback function for the observer
function callback(mutationRecord) {
    console.log("Number of mutations : ", mutationRecord.length);
    for (let i = 0, len = mutationRecord.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      console.log("target : ", mutationRecord[i].target);
      console.log("type : ", mutationRecord[i].type);
      console.log("attributeName : ", mutationRecord[i].attributeName);
      console.log("oldValue : ", mutationRecord[i].oldValue);
    }
  }
 
//Sets the configuration for the observation of an Target (Looking for attributes, childs and cd)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// adding the observer to every target with the class a
for(let i = 0;i<targets.length;i++){
    observer.observe(targets[i], config);
    
}

 
// When you dont wanna observer anymore, you can use observer.disconnect();
//observer.disconnect();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

       
        .a.marked{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="a"> 18 </div>
<div class="b"> 45 </div>
<div class="a"> 50 </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Comment: And how do I do if i cant click on the div ?
I mean, i dont want to interact with the div.

Comment: I just created it for an example, because only with the 3 div elements, the page is static. You need to change something, so you can look for a change. When you add the Observer to the target, you will see the changes.